# LINQ query works in LinqPad but errors in .NET Application

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following LINQ query that is working when I test in LinqPad:

```
var query =  this._dbContext.SHIPMENT_HEADER
            .Join(
                this._dbContext.SHIPMENT_DETAIL
                h => h.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM,
                d => d.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM,
                (a, b) => new { Header = a, Detail = b })
            .Where(s => s.Header.SHIPMENT_ID == shipmentId)
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.Header.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, g.Header.ORDER_NUM })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                InternalShipmentNumber = x.Key.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM,
                OrderNumber = x.Key.ORDER_NUM,
                OrderLines = x.Select(l => new
                {
                    InternalLineNumber = l.Detail.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM,
                    LineNumber = l.Detail.ORDER_LINE_NUM ?? 0,
                }),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I move it to a .Net application using EF Core 3.1, I get this error:

```
{"The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { 
    INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = (s.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM), 
    ORDER_NUM = (s.ERP_ORDER)  },  ElementSelector:new { 
    Header = (EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: SHIPMENT_HEADER
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: Header)
        IsNullable: False
    ), 
    Detail = (EntityShaperExpression: 
        EntityType: SHIPMENT_DETAIL
        ValueBufferExpression: 
            (ProjectionBindingExpression: Detail)
        IsNullable: False
    )  } )
    .Select(l => new { 
        InternalLineNumber = l.Detail.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM, 
        LineNumber = l.Detail.ORDER_LINE_NUM ?? 0
     })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()."}
```

I'm not able to make sense of the error message?

Comment: Actually this query is not translatable by EF Core 3.1. Do you use EF6 driver for LINQPad?

Comment: Is LINQPad using the same EF Core version?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using EF6 driver in LinqPad.  Any ideas how to alter the query for EF Core 3.1?

Comment: Yes, sure. But I think query can be rewritten. Grouping here looks suspicious. Can you show your model classes with navigation properties?

Comment: i can only assume, since you did not show class structure with navigation, but try to set OrderLines  = x.Select(....).ToList(),

Comment: This is not a good query to begin with. EF isn't a database driver or embedded SQL library. It's an ORM, whose job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. There shouldn't be any need for JOINs. It's *EF*'s job to generate the JOINs from the relations between objects.

Comment: As for why EF Core fails, this query isn't trying to do a GROUP BY. There are no aggregate functions in the `Select` after `GroupBy`. It tries to *reshape* the flat results into a hierarchy. This probably worked in the Framework version of EF because it retrieved the *flat* results then reshaped them  in memory. You can do the same explicitly by adding a `.ToList()` before `GroupBy`. You should add a `Select` before `ToList()` to retrieve only the data you need

Comment: BTW EF Core 3.1 is out of support. I suspect EF Core 6 will be able to handle this. EF Core 3.1 cut out a lot of the client-side evaluation tricks EF Core 1-2 did to hide missing features, like the complete lack of `GROUP BY` in EF Core 1. Later EF Core versions added back *some* client-side evaluations and fixups that didn't risk loading more data than developers intended